# Laravel 7 - Redirects to the main page when the optional parameter is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

I have a route with an optional parameter in `web.php`:

my `web.php`: (the route that has the problem is marked with a comment)

```php
Route::middleware(['auth', 'dashboard'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@home')->name('root');

    Route::prefix('/drivers')->group(function () {
        Route::view('/', 'dashboard.driver.main');
        Route::post('/', 'UserController@addDriver');

        Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
            if (Auth::user()->can('view_user')) {
                $user = User::find($id);
                return view('dashboard.user.view', ['user' => $user]);
            }
            return view('pages.403');
        });


       //----------------------------------------
       // My route with the problem
       // ---------------------------------------
        Route::get('/driver-dropdown/{q?}', function ($q=null){
            return $q;
        })->name('driver.dropdown');
    });
});
```

and it is my `dashboard` middleware:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if(!in_array(\Auth::user()->getOriginal('role'), ['superadmin', 'admin', 'supporter']) )
    {
        return abort(403);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

When I enter the `host-name/drivers/driver-dropdown/jo` URL, I get **jo**
**BUT** When I enter the `host-name/drivers/driver-dropdown/` URL,  I will be redirected to the `host-name/` that means root route!

**Edit:** updated `web.php`

Comment: what happens with host-name/drivers/driver-dropdown (without the last slash) ?

Comment: @wschopohl same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should reorder your routes like this:

```php
        Route::get('/driver-dropdown/{q?}', function ($q=null){
            return $q;
        })->name('driver.dropdown');

        Route::get('/{id}', function ($id) {
            if (Auth::user()->can('view_user')) {
                $user = User::find($id);
                return view('dashboard.user.view', ['user' => $user]);
            }
            return view('pages.403');
        });
```

Currently, when you go to `host-name/drivers/driver-dropdown/`, it will match the `/{id}` route.

Answer (score 0):

If I’m correct the URL’s in your routes which are grouped shouldn’t start with a `/`, except for the main route of course. I’ve had this issue too.

Should be like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'dashboard'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@home')->name('root');
 
    Route::prefix('drivers')->group(function () {
        Route::get('driver-dropdown/{q?}', function ($q=null){
            return $q;
        })->name('driver.dropdown');
    });
});
```

Comment: Do you mean the code inside this link? https://pastebin.com/rvQS8ib2

Comment: @hamed I’ve updated my answer. Could you let me if this is working?

Comment: same problem! but I updated my question `web.php`. this is my all routes